# zf2 - pass argument to service manager

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a factory service, in which i want to send additional argument from the controller, here is how i am doing it currently.

```
$apiSuccess = new ApiSuccess(array(
    'status' => 'success',
    'code' => 'user_authenticate_success',
    'href' => 'app/welcome',
    'message' => 'User Authenticated Successfully'
));

$apiResponse = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('api_response');
$apiResponse->setHttpCode(200);
$apiResponse->setContent($apiSuccess);
$apiResponse->dispatch();
```

Here is my factory service class

```
class ApiJsonResponseFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return new ApiJsonResponseService($serviceLocator);
    }
}
```

Here is my invokable service class:

```
class ApiJsonResponseService
{
    protected $serviceManager;

    protected $httpCode = null;

    protected $content = null;

    public function __construct(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceManager)
    {
        $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getServiceManager()
    {
        return $this->serviceManager;
    }

    public function setHttpCode($httpCode)
    {
        $this->httpCode = $httpCode;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getHttpCode()
    {
        return $this->httpCode;
    }

    public function setContent(ApiBaseResponseInterface $content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function dispatch()
    {
        if (null === $this->httpCode) {
            throw new \Exception('Invalid or missing HTTP Code, set valid HTTP code using setHttpCode()');
        }
        if (null === $this->content) {
            throw new \Exception('Invalid or missing content');
        }
        $response = $this->getServiceManager()->get('Response');
        $response->setStatusCode($this->getHttpCode());
        $apiJsonResponse = new ApiJsonResponse($this->content);
        return $apiJsonResponse->dispatch();
    }
}
```

This is working as expected, I am wondering if there is any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass parameters to the service manager, although, you CAN pass parameters to an AbstractPluginManager. That said, I wouldn't use that strategy for this.

I also wouldn't pass the ServiceManager to your `ApiJsonResponseService` class. The service manager is only getting the Response object, why not just pass the response object itself.

your first code block becomes:

```
$apiSuccess = new ApiSuccess(array(
    'status' => 'success',
    'code' => 'user_authenticate_success',
    'href' => 'app/welcome',
    'message' => 'User Authenticated Successfully'
));

$response = $this->getResponse();
$apiResponse = new ApiJsonResponseService($response, 200, $apiSuccess);
$apiResponse->dispatch();
```

Obviously you would also have to update the constructor, and the availability of the response depends on where you are in the app / if you injected it.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, what i don't like is making ApiJsonResponseService dependent on $response object, imagine if i require request object for some reason, I may end up changing a lot of code, rather i would rely on service manager to give me what i need, +1 for letting me know i cannot pass the parameters in service manager.

Comment: I see your point, but the "What if" game can make for some pretty awful interfaces. In this case, you're not truly injecting your dependencies. You're forcing this class to have knowledge of the service manager (and how to retrieve the Request object) when all it really needs to do it's job is the Request.